# Synchronise Web Notifications on Multiple Browsers/Devices

Tags: javascript, java, push-notification, web-notifications

How do I synchronise Web Notifications on multiple Browsers/Devices?

Assume my server would be able to know whether user has accessed a notification within their account on my web app (and which device they accessed it from.)

Then is it possible to mark that notification as "read" on all other subscribed devices (for that user)?  Is there a Javascript API to mark (already received and listed) notifications as read?  Or some other way to synchronise notifications?

Reading through related threads on Stack Overflow... I came across a mention of PubNub.  Apparently it manages notifications on multiple devices.  I don't want to use a third-party service... I just need to know the mechanism for doing it.

Comment: Usually notifications are fire and forget, like an email or sms. You just send it to all the user devices and, in case, the user can unsubscribe from a device if it finds duplicated notifications annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Using a third party API isn't necessarily a bad option for your use case since if you chose to went with PubNub, you wouldn't have to setup any of the backend infrastructure yourself.  In addition, you won't have to worry about scaling issues if your application takes off.

PubNub synchronizes notifications across devices in real time using technology known as Publish Subscribe. It's a highly scalable protocol that is fast, reliable and efficient.  Checkout the Javascript mobile push SDK [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-mobile-push)

[image]

In the callback function, you will receive a response that tells you when the notification has been read.  The API is pretty straightforward, and easy to follow. Check it out and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: How is synchronisation possible?  What's the mechanism for it. How did they crack withdrawing a web notification (when there is no API to do that).  I guessing that they mean something else by "Synchronisation".

This is for an application with a very large user-base (we just don't have notifications yet).  We are smart enough to have solved the scaling issues - thank you.